# Javascript: decrypt string encrypted with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, cryptography

I've code in PHP to encrypt string.

```php
$password = 'secret';
$iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-256-CBC');
$key = substr(sha1($password, true), 0, $iv_length);
$string = 'Brevity is the soul of wit';
$iv = hex2bin('2ceb02a85f6d4de6c28b2e59fda886d5');
$encrypted_string = openssl_encrypt($string, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
echo base64_encode($encrypted_string);
```

It returns encrypted text in base64 `Ky27sjhxUY7BFoscEgyFToxRDAsARzRFgQBIApbPmjQ=`.
I'm passing it and IV to javascript and trying to decrypt using this code:

```js
const crypto = require("crypto");
const Algorithm = "aes-256-cbc";

function encrypt(plainText, key, iv, outputEncoding = "base64") {
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(Algorithm, key, iv);
    const output = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(plainText), cipher.final()]).toString(outputEncoding);
    return output.replace('+', '-').replace('/', '_').replace('=', '');
}

function decrypt(cipherText, key, iv, outputEncoding = "base64") {
    cipherText = Buffer.from(cipherText.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/'), "base64");
    const cipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(Algorithm, key, iv, {

    });
    return Buffer.concat([cipher.update(cipherText), cipher.final()]).toString(outputEncoding);
}

const string = "Brevity is the soul of wit";

const password = 'secret';
const iv_length = 16;
let KEY = crypto
    .createHash('sha1')
    .update(password)
    .digest('bin')
    .slice(0, iv_length);

const IV = Buffer.from('2ceb02a85f6d4de6c28b2e59fda886d5', 'hex');

const decrypted = decrypt('GIyzBeAUpxr93RIyjUZZ6W4lm/qHiF1lf/8drSEgfGs=', KEY, IV, "utf8")
console.log("Decrypted:", decrypted);
```

But it fails with this error:

```
internal/crypto/cipher.js:103
    this[kHandle].initiv(cipher, credential, iv, authTagLength);
                  ^

Error: Invalid key length
    at Decipheriv.createCipherBase (internal/crypto/cipher.js:103:19)
    at Decipheriv.createCipherWithIV (internal/crypto/cipher.js:121:20)
    at new Decipheriv (internal/crypto/cipher.js:264:22)
    at Object.createDecipheriv (crypto.js:130:10)
    at decrypt (/Users/sacram/code/decrypt/test.js:12:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sacram/code/decrypt/test.js:36:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
```

Is it possible to decrypt it without modifying PHP code?

I'm trying to decrypt string using js which was encrypted in php

Comment: The NodeJS code is missing a `KEY = Buffer.concat([KEY, Buffer.alloc(16, '\0')])`, which happens implicitly in the PHP code (padding of too short keys). Note, SHA1 and appending 0x00 values in key derivation are vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Topaco do you want to post an answer or is it a duplicate or existing question?

Comment: @Topaco could you please post your comment as an answer and I will accept it as a valid answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. I put my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both codes, the length of the key is determined from the specified algorithm: `AES-256-CBC` requires a 32 bytes key.

In the PHP/OpenSSL code, the first 16 bytes of the SHA-1 hash of the password are used as key. The too short key is *silently* padded with 0x00 values to the required length of 32 bytes (a too long key would be *silently* truncated to the required length at the end), see the description of the *passphrase* parameter in the [`openssl_encrypt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) documentation.

In the NodeJS code, the key is also determined as the first 16 bytes of the SHA-1 hash of the password. However, unlike the PHP/OpenSSL code, the key is neither silently padded (nor truncated). A key of the wrong length is identified as invalid and a corresponding exception is thrown. This is the reason for the exception raised in the NodeJS code.

So that the same key is used in the NodeJS code as in the PHP code, the following must be added to the NodeJS code:

```js
KEY = Buffer.concat([KEY, Buffer.alloc(16, '\0')])
```

---

The PHP code has a number of vulnerabilities:

- The use of a fast digest for key derivation: Instead, a dedicated key derivation function (KDF) such as Argon2 or at least PBKDF2 should be used (to slow down possible attackers). Here, for each encryption, a random salt is to be applied, which is passed along with the ciphertext to the decrypting side, usually concatenated (the salt is not secret).
- The extension of the key from 16 to 32 bytes with 0x00 values: Instead a 32 bytes key should be generated *directly* (although this could be achieved with a suitable digest, such as SHA256, a KDF should be applied, as mentioned in the previous section; note that KDFs allow the key size to be specified).
- The use of a static IV: Instead, for each encryption, a random IV should be generated and passed along with the ciphertext to the decrypting side, usually concatenated (the IV is not secret). For testing purposes, of course, a static IV is fine.